# Can't connect to Analysis Services or Reporting Services on localhost

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssrs

I'm able to connect to my SQL Server 2008R2 localhost Database Engine and Integration Services.

However, when I try to connect to Analysis Services, it fails with the message: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

I didn't get an error when I tried to connect to Reporting Services, but didn't get a response of any kind after 10 minutes and canceled the connection attempt.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Is the SSAS server actually running? - you can check this in the services control panel.

Comment: That was the first thing I checked. It appeared to be running, but I restarted it just to be sure -- same results.

Comment: May be this MSDN link might help http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917670.aspx it is for SQL Server 2005 but worth a try

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2658571 This fixes the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the original installation was bad. I uninstalled and re-installed and now everything is working as it should.